# Matrix exponential weirdness in WolframAlpha - it fails on diagonal matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, wolfram-alpha, matrix-exponential

So Wikipedia says this, which makes sense:

[image: Wikipedia]

But Wolfram computed this:

[image: Wolfram]

Is this a bug or am I just extremely tired?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For the matrix exponential, use MatrixExp instead of Exp. Wolfram Alpha interprets Exp to be the entrywise exponentiation.

Comment: I think Wolfram Alpha also multiplies matrices entrywise when not otherwise instructed

Comment: @J.W.Tanner: No: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B0%2C1%7D%2C%7B1%2C0%7D%7D%2A%7B%7B0%2C1%7D%2C%7B1%2C0%7D%7D

Comment: @Troposphere:  maybe [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=product+of+%7B%7B0%2C1%7D%2C%7B1%2C0%7D%7Dand+%7B%7B0%2C1%7D%2C%7B1%2C0%7D%7D) or [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=multiply+%7B%7B0%2C1%7D%2C%7B1%2C0%7D%7D++by+%7B%7B0%2C1%7D%2C%7B1%2C0%7D%7D) is what I was thinking of

Answer (score 0):

In *Mathematica*:

```
MatrixExp[{{2, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 3, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 4, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 5}}]
```

(* {{E^2, 0, 0, 0}, {0, E^3, 0, 0}, {0, 0, E^4, 0}, {0, 0, 0, E^5}} *)

```
N@% //MatrixForm
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 7.38906 & 0. & 0. & 0. \\
 0. & 20.0855 & 0. & 0. \\
 0. & 0. & 54.5982 & 0. \\
 0. & 0. & 0. & 148.413 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$